# How to make frontend Gallery.view codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, frontend, backend

I already have both controller, models and view for backend and frontend page gallery. But somehow my frontend gallery cannot connect, meanwhile, my backend already could connect to the database and do function like crud. I don't know where I went wrong can someone help me?

controllers: galleryweb.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Galleryweb extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("galleryweb_model");
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data["gallery"] = $this->galleryweb_model->getAll();
        $this->load->view("front/gallery", $data);
    }
}
```

Models: Galleryweb_model.php

```
class Galleryweb_model extends CI_Model
{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    private $_table = "gallery";

    public $id_gallery;
    public $name;
    public $image;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['field' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Name',
            'rules' => 'required']
        ];
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->db->get($this->_table)->result();
    }

    public function getById($id)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where($this->_table, ["id_gallery" => $id])->row();
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $post = $this->input->post();
        $this->id_gallery = uniqid();
        $this->name = $post["name"];
        $this->image = $this->_uploadImage();
        $this->db->insert($this->_table, $this);
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $post = $this->input->post();
        $this->id_gallery = $post["id"];
        $this->name = $post["name"];
        if (!empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])) {
            $this->image = $this->_uploadImage();
        } else {
            $this->image = $post["old_image"];
        }
        $this->db->update($this->_table, $this, array('id_gallery' => $post['id']));
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->_deleteImage($id);
        return $this->db->delete($this->_table, array("id_gallery" => $id));
    }

    private function _uploadImage()
    {
        $config['upload_path']          = './upload/galery/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['upload_max_filesize']  = '100000M';
        $config['post_max_size']        = '100000M';
        $config['file_name']            = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        $config['overwrite']            = true;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
            return $this->upload->data("file_name");
        }
    }

    private function _deleteImage($id)
    {
        $gallery = $this->getById($id);
        if ($gallery->image != "default.jpg") {
            $filename = explode(".", $gallery->image)[0];
            return array_map('unlink', glob(FCPATH."upload/galery/$filename.*"));
        }
    }
}
```

View: front: gallery.php

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-4 thumb">
                <?php foreach ($gallery as $gallery): ?>
                <a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo $gallery->name ?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery"> 
                    <img class="img-polaroid" src="<?php echo base_url('upload/galery/'.$gallery->image) ?>" alt="" /> 
                </a>
                <?php?>
            </div> 
            <nav aria-label="Page navigation example ">
                <center>
                    <ul class="pagination align-center">
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"> 
                            <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </center>
            </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your question is too broad and unspecific. What exactly are you having issues with? Are you simply asking how to pass data from the controller to the view? Then you should read CI's documentation. If that's not what you're asking, then you need to clarify your question.

Comment: I didn't get what are you trying to say. Are you looking for $this->load->view('name');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->load->model("gallery_model");` but model name is Galleryweb_model?

Comment: I already changed it to galleryweb_model but it still errors like this:                                     An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ParseError

Message: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\eat\application\views\front\gallery.php

Line Number: 261

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\eat\application\controllers\galleryweb.php
Line: 16
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\eat\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once